# Twitter4J: Search Tweets by HashTag, get JSON result only

Tags: json, twitter, jersey, twitter4j, hashtag

I have a term project, in which part of it is parsing a twitter JSON object. I am using Jersey and JAX-RS
I have originally tried to parse it directly using my Jersey client, and this was my original code:
(original link: https:// api.twitter. com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23coldplay)

```
public static String lastFMHTTP() {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    String Str = client.target("https://api.twitter.com/")
                        .path("1.1")
                        .path("tweets.json?")
                        .queryParam("q", "#coldplay")
                        .queryParam("result_type", "recent")
                        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)   
                        .get(String.class);
    return Str;
}
```

But this didn't turn out too well; I don't understand how to pass tweets.json? as a parameter, and this would have returned a "bad authentication data" anyways (I tried another method of parsing without paths and queryparams). This code worked for my lastfm request however. The api key is included in the URL

After some searching, I've twitter4j, which is a library made specifically for this purpose. I have managed to successfully receive a JSON response. This is the code that I am using:

```
public static String twitterHTTP() throws TwitterException {
    Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
    Query query = new Query("#coldplay");
    QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
    return result;
}
```

When I run this method, object.twitterHTTP();
It prints information into my console. I don't need anything to be printed at all, I just need it to return a string in JSON format.

What is my best option?
Is there a way to authenticate twitter through the first code, or is there a way to remove all the prints from the second code and have it return a string object?
Thanks

Comment: `"tweets.json?"` <- the `?` shouldn't be there. It is appended implicitly with your use of query parameters.

Comment: _" It prints all sorts of junk information into my console"_ - One developer's "junk" is another developer's treasure (at least in the sense of informational treasure :-) Maybe it wants to tell you something.

Comment: @peeskillet I tried removing it, but it failed to even give me the status code error
junk: arrrghh

Answer (score 0):

Eureka, I've got it. I'm so happy that I can die now.
Debug was set to true on my twitter4j.properties file, which was why I got all those "junk" information printed out, which actually turned out to be the log. Setting debug to false solved the problem, and the logs were no longer printed.

And it turned out that I didn't actually need that JSON reponse to be returned as an individual string; the reason why I wanted this was to create classes/methods and objects to parse the JSON response when in reality, the twitter4j library provided methods to do the parsing. Thus, I don't need to create new code.